# How do I keep data private using the role hierarchy and org-wide defaults?

Tags: role-hierarchy, owd, adm201

I have one org and three users in it.

1st user is owner with role owner.
and 2 user is manger with same role manager.

Now I want to keep to manger data private to each other so they only can see their data.

and owner can see both of them data.

I set up role Hierarchy and also make private OWD for that object but still record visible to each other.

Comment: Could you update your question title to be more relevant?

Comment: Hi Parth, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Certification questions aren't generally on topic here, not any question where you cannot demonstrate that you have not made an attempt to solve your own problem. I didn't downvote, but that's the likely reason you've received one so far. Try to show what you've looked into.

Comment: I do visit there and learn how to ask , i've just join this blog.

Comment: This site is not a blog, it is a terse Q&A site. You should read the [faq] in addition to the resources I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create sharing rules for the objects that you want set like this.

To do this, you will need to either set each of your managers in a different role, or create 2 public groups, each with one manager in it.

After you have done that, on the settings page, search for Sharing Settings. Then, scroll down to see the different objects within your org. Under the object header, click the New button.

Give the Sharing Rule a name.

Set it so that each role or group can only share to it's own role or group.

Set your access level to read/write.

You will need to do this 3 times on each object, one for each manager, and a third that says that if the owner is an internal user, share with owner role.

***EDIT***

Based on the comments, you will also need to remove the Read/Modify all flags from the manager. Those 2 flags will override sharing and field lock rules.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , I try it i create two role assign to each manager and create thee Sharing Rule and set it witch each role but still visible in each other.

Comment: Are the profiles set to View All and/or Modify All?

Comment: Yes it is set to View All & Modify All

Comment: I updated the answer. You will need to remove those as well. Those flags override sharing and lockout rules. They really should only be set for the user(s) who need to see everything in the system, regardless of rules. Typically with our programs, this would be the System Administrator account or similar.

Comment: I remove that permission but still no good news , it might be small thing for you but i am new to admin side.

Comment: Based on my experience, I am not sure what else would be causing this issue.